# Fragment onCreateView Calls Again when I call fragment function from Main Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment-oncreateview

Actually my problem is I want to send string from Main Activity to My Fragment on button clickListner but when I call fragment function from Main activity, onCreateView of fragment calls again and everything Initialize again. Please guide me how can I avoid this problem thanks.

Here is My MainActivity code:

```
ThirdFragment thirdFragment=new ThirdFragment();
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.thirdfragment,thirdFragment,null);
                           fragmentTransaction.commitNow();
                            ThirdFragment fragment = (ThirdFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.thirdfragment);
                           if(fragment!=null) {
                               fragment.Subcategories(text);

                           }
```

Here is Fragment Function code:

```
public void Subcategories(String text){

    Log.d(TAG, "Subcategories: fragment calling "+text);

        mAPIService.searchcategory("2",text).enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<DataStored>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<DataStored>> call, Response<ArrayList<DataStored>> response) {
               myRecyclerAdapter.addItems(response.body());
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<DataStored>> call, Throwable t) {
                myRecyclerAdapter.addItems(null);


            }
        });


}
```

Comment: i have some confusion regarding your question.are you need only called the fragment’s method or also need to place the fragment?

Comment: no just want to call fragment's method

Answer (score 0):

try like this;`

```
 ThirdFragment thirdFragment=new ThirdFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.thirdfragment,thirdFragment,null);
                               fragmentTransaction.commitNow();
                                ThirdFragment fragment = (ThirdFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.thirdfragment);
                               if(fragment!=null) {
                                   fragment.Subcategories(text);

                               } `
```

Comment: try to use commit() instead of commitNow(); . if it does not work, remove it with the fragment remove () method that you have previously loaded. Add the newly loaded fragment with the add () method. It needs to work.

Comment: now I am getting this error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setNextAnim(int)' on a null object reference